Janiusgraph 1.0 Data location
I am using Janusgraph 1.0 docker janusgraph/janusgraph:1.0.0, I have done configuration in janusgraph-cql-es.properties to point it to Cassandra as storage.backend and ES as index.search.backend.
Question : Will it save all vertex and edges in Cassandra and ES and nothing locally, or it does still save data locally in data folder?
My observation is that I see some files in data folder under janus getting create upon vertex creation. So want to check, if I am missing anything or it is how janus is suppose to work.

Please show exactly how you start the JanusGraph container and how you configure it. How did you tell JanusGraph to use your janusgraph-cql-es.properties?
JanusGraph shouldn't store anything if it's configured to use CQL(Cassandra) + ES as its backends. So, this sounds like your configuration isn't working correctly.
